# How to print UTF-8 chars in ncurses?

Tags: unicode, ncurses

Traditionally I can perfectly print this:

```
char str[] = "▄█▀█████";
printf(str);
```

However, under ncurses I cannot print this string neither with:

```
mvprintw(0, 0, str);
```

nor with:

```
mvaddwstr(0,0, L"▄█▀█████");
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whooh, this was quick... I already solved it; dear nowox:

You forgot to configure your locales:

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```